# git repoint to new remote repository

Tags: git, magento2

I run on a Mac OSX.  I have pulled down a vagrant box that is compatible with Magento, and then pulled down the Magento 2.0 codebase (develop branch) via `git clone`, and successfully installed it.

I now have an installed, configured codebase tailored to our company.  What I wan to do is:

1. repoint where my local repo considers "master" or "origin" to exist to our company URL
2. to a git push (I think that is correct) of the code to this blank repository.

The logic is, now the dev team can pull that into their vagrant box, do a mysql import of the resultant database, and skip the install.

How do I do #1 and #2?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For #1, you can use `git remote set-url`, like so:

```
git remote set-url origin https://company.example.com/git/repo/path/
```

For #2, you can do a few different things. If you only have a `master` branch to push, simply use `git push origin master`. If you want to push all branches, you can use `git push origin refs/remotes/origin/*:refs/heads/*`, which will push every `origin`-branch that your local Git repository knows about to `origin`.

Comment: just for a user's reference, the first command modified .git/config inside the root, editing the file manually would also be very intuitive.  Worked, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

`git remote set-url origin url/to/company/repo` will change what the `origin` repository URL is. For the second part, you'll first need to initialize a bare repository at that URL, and then you can push to it.

Comment: what would be the command to initialize a bare repository with name `my_repo` for example?

Comment: `git init --bare my_repo`